# abstract algebra field subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. Let $D\subseteq F$ be a subring of $F$ with the multiplicative identity. Put $D'=\{$ $ab^{-1}$ $:$ $a,b\in D$ , $b\neq 0$ $\}$. Then $D'$ is a subfield of $F$.

I'm in particular stuck with showing that every non-zero is a unit.

Here is my attempt so far:
First, I will show that $D'$ is a subring of $F$. Indeed, $0\in D'$. Hence $D'$ is non-empty. Suppose $ab^{-1},cd^{-1}\in D'$. Then, $ab^{-1}-cd^{-1}=(ad-bc)(bd)^{-1}$. Since $D$ is an integral domain, $bd\neq 0$. Therefore the difference is in $D'$. Suppose $ab^{-1},cd^{-1}$ is in $D'$. Then, $(ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})=ac(bd)^{-1}\in D'$. Therefore $D'$ is a commutative subring. Note that $1\in D'$ and $1\neq 0$. Lastly, I will show that $D'$ is a division ring.

Comment: Please do not delete  your posts. The content is here for everybody to read.

Comment: @quid Right. My apologies. The question was based of me misreading the problem, so I didn’t think it would be helpful for anyone. My apologies

Comment: Yes I understand the sentiment, yet generally once an answer is given it is best to avoid deletion. .

Answer (score 2):

Let $ab^{-1}\in D’$ with $b\neq 0$, $a,b\in D$. If $a=0$ then $ab^{-1}=0$ and there is nothing to do. If $a\neq 0$, then isn’t $ba^{-1}\in D’$?

Comment: but $a^{-1}$ may not be in $D$, no?

Comment: The definition of $D’$ does not require $a^{-1}\in D$. The definition of $D’$ requires two elements of $D$, with the second one nonzero.

Comment: Right, sorry.  For some reason I kept misreading it.